# Components and connecteness

Tags: general-topology

Let E be a component of Y and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Then $f^{-1}(E)$ is a union of components of X.

Can you give me some ideas?, because I can not see any way to build the union of the components for $f^{-1}(E)$

Comment: Why are you writing $E$ as a union of components when you’re given the hypothesis that $E$ ***is*** a component of $Y$?

Answer (score 2):

**hints** continuous image of a conneceted set is connected...suppose $a \in f^{-1}(E)$ and let $a \in A$ is a component in $X$ so $f^{-1}(E) \cap A \neq \phi$ then $f(A) \cap E \neq \phi$...since $E$ is a component and $f(A)$ is connected so $f(A) \subset E$...thus $A \subset f^{-1}(E)$ ...

here I am assuming  component as a maximal connected set...for path-connected set also the same argument is valid.